Request bibliographic reference(s) for finite alternating sums with Eulerian numbers
I would like to know a bibliographic reference for a math formula. I found this formula on Wikipedia, but no reference is given.
It's the 2nd formula ($A(n,k)$ is an Eulerian number):
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\,(-1)^k\,\frac{A(n,k)}{\binom{n-1}{k}}=0\,,$$
for $n>1$ (there are 3) in the chapter entitled "Formulas involving alternating sums" on the Wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number
I've looked at lots of (very complicated...) articles, but there's nothing obvious about this formula. Handbooks of Mathematics, etc. nothing, nothing, nothing...!
Does anyone have a bibliographical reference to suggest?
Thank you.

Your question could be much improved if you make it entirely self-contained by using $\LaTeX$ to write the identity you want a reference for.
